# SlideToggle issue

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am using a code which needs to slidetoggle() the menu, when clicking an Arrow image.  But the arrow is not sliding along with the menu.  can any one help me?  The Arrow needs to be displayed in the bottom of the page.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul id="frisherVertical">
        <li>Fresher Academy</li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Offerings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Latest Event</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>         

<div class="footer1">
    <div class="footer2">
        <p id = "copyright">All rights are reserved &copy; 2014 | <a href="#" id = "pri_pol">Privacy Policy</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide_menu">            
        <img src="../imgs/up_arrow.png" id="slideArrow"/>  
    </div>    
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".footer1").click(function(){                     
        $("#slider").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.footer1 {
    position:relative;
    top: 460px;
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#FFB919;
}

.footer2 {  
    position:absolute;
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#298CB5;
}

#slider {
    display:none;
    padding: 5px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 990px;
    left: 0px;
}

#copyright {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to a FIDDLE and it didn't work, but I got rid of all of the positioning stuff and it works fine. For a simple layout like yours, just stick with regular positioning unless you really have to do something odd.

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2vta6yo8/) seems to do the slidetoggle - I'll let you play with the styling.

CSS

```
.footer1 {
    background-color:#FFB919;
}

.footer2 {   
    background-color:#298CB5;
}

#slider {
    display:none;
    padding: 5px;
}

#copyright {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#FFF;
}
```